# Limiting the results of a mysql query to the first matches only

Tags: mysql

I have the following mySQL query to collect prices for various domain names.

```
SELECT tdp.extension, tp.msetupfee
FROM tblpricing tp
INNER JOIN tbldomainpricing tdp ON tdp.id = tp.relid 
WHERE tp.type = 'domainregister' AND tp.msetupfee > 0
```

The problem is that when it outputs the data to screen it is using the last record returned. 
What I want to do is limit it to only returning the first value per domain type.

I have set up a fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59aeac/1 and you can see that for .com it returns 11.35 then 9.23. I only want 11.35
I tried adding LIMIT 1 but that just made it return the first domain only. What is the cleanest solution to this issue?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @1000111As stated in the question, looking at the results returned from the fiddle I would only want to see .com return 11.35, and .ie return 20

Comment: One more question: How do you define the **first value per domain type**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `GROUP BY tdp.id`to the query - this should help...